# How to record a live stream using Python?

Tags: python, vlc

I want to record a live stream to computer, buffer it and play it using VLC with some delay thus to get a smoother stream. I want to do it using Python. What I've now is packet capture using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). But, how to make a video file out of it and then show it in VLC or any other player on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try [pyffmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/). You might need to test each available codec to see what perf suits you. You have a trade off between latency of the video encoding and decoding and the bandwidth used. But worth a look for your case at hand...

Answer (score 0):

```
i=vlc.Instance(b'--fullscreen',b"--sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=ts,dst = 'C:\\Users\\lxislx\\Desktop\\x.avi')}}")
p=i.media_player_new()

m=i.media_new(b'http://admin:admin@192.168.1.4:8080/videofeed')

m.get_mrl()

p.set_media(m)

p.play()
```

Comment: please provide link to any non builtin module. and some explanation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit a tricky, but you can capture ports and save file with output!